# Why won't this putpixel loop work? Python 2.7, PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Ok so I'm basically gathering sets of pixels of photos into one big set. I then want this set to become a picture so I can easily transfer the data across to another program (I tried having it read from a file. Was terrible).

Anyway, I keep getting

```
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Here's my code

```
print z_set[0:10]
print len(z_set)
print type(z_set)
W= len(z_set)
H=1
img=Image.new("RGB",(W,H))
N=1
M=0

if N!=len(z_set):
    img.putpixel((N,1),z_set[M])
    N=N+1
    M=M+1
    print 'done'
```

Here's what the prints put out, incase that's useful information.

```
((26, 44, 0), (45, 88, 6), (106, 170, 84), (52, 105, 37), (121, 157, 87), (57, 118, 49), (136, 205, 63), (80, 167, 88), (135, 162, 131), (86, 109, 37))
128303
<type 'tuple'>
```

These are my imports. I think the only important one to mention is PIL, but here they all are anyway.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import Image
```

Why won't this work? I've fiddled with the values but it always seems to have same issue?

Comment: Your image is 1 pixel high. You're trying to set pixel `(N,1)`. Indexing starts at 0. Connect the dots.

Comment: I believe the Image class uses 0-indexing just like all other lists and arrays in python. So just do `[img.putpixel((index, 0), value) for index, value in enumerate(z_set)]` instead